# Next JS error using appwrite in the backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, appwrite

I am having problem with a project that i am currently working on. It is a Twitter Clone application, i have the error it says the following image:

This is the image of the error on the server(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Hhvs.png)

The above given picture is what i am being shown when i run my next js application i am using appwrite nextjs and tailwind css. Can any one please tell me how to fix this error. I tried but it is not working. BTW if you want the code file of the error shown file that is the index.js file here it is:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Databases } from 'appwrite';
import appwriteClient from '@/libs/appwrite';

import Feed from '@/components/Feed';
import MainLayout from '@/components/Layouts/MainLayout';

export default function Home({ tweets }) {
  return (
    <MainLayout>
      <Feed tweets={tweets.documents} />
    </MainLayout>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const databases = new Databases(appwriteClient);

  const tweets = await databases.listDocuments(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATABASE,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TWEETS_COLLECTION
  );
  return {
    props: { tweets }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}
```

Comment: I would guess your database ID is being passed as undefined. If you run `console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATABASE);` in the getServerSideProps() function, what do you get?

Comment: Do not post pictures of text when you can post the text itself.  You have made this question unsearchable for those who have similar errors.